# How big to make a perfect cube? And how to build it

Tags: building

I want to make a model, that involves many cubes. I want to make many individual cubes, then connect them together. I don't want my cubes to be that big. That leads to my first question: What is the smallest sized PERFECT cube I can make? My second question is: How do I make it?

> A perfect Cube: In LEGO terms: A structure whose dimensions are n x n x n, excluding studs.

And I forgot to mention that I can only have basic bricks. No plates or tiles. Sorry!

P.S. I really am annoying aren't I?!

Also, I don't require it to connect, and even if I could, I couldn't anyway,because I am using Basic Blocks. For the people asking, I am making a pillar, balanced

Comment: Do you have any requirements on connectability and stability?

Comment: Can you show us what you are planning to do? How are you going to connect the cubes?

Answer (score 6):

The smallest perfect cube you can make is a 2x2 brick with a 2x2 plate and a 2x2 tile on top.

And now I read that you're excluding studs, then you can use a plate instead of at tile, and obviously the order in which you stack the elements doesn't matter.

Comment: So your cube is 2x2x(1+2/3). This means that without plates you would need 6 x 6 x 5 (length x width x height) as the smallest possible cube (?)

Comment: The ratio between the height and width of one brick is 6:5, so yes, if you have to it out of only standard bricks, that will be the size.

Answer (score 4):

LEGO's height to width ratio is 6:5. Since the smallest common multiple of these numbers is 30, the smallest perfect cube you can make (excluding studs) is one that is 5 bricks high and 6 bricks deep and wide.

EDIT: On how to build it: start with a layer of 3 2x6 bricks. Then place 2x 1x4 on two sides to join the 2x6 bricks, and complete a square by using 2x 1x6. Now make alternating layers of 1x6 and 1x4 bricks to make it strong, and top it off with another 3x 2x6 bricks as the fifth layer.